# Can not connect mysql

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu

I just install mysql-server in my laptop with some of command like this:

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During time of install, i did not receive any prompt about asign password for root user, then i try to reset password of root account, i try some way in internet but when i do it i received error:

```
2020-08-27T08:25:54.149679Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

or

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I command `find / -type s` and search socket file in laptop for mysql but i can not find anything for mysql.

And finally i decided to reinstall mysql but when i command `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` to remove mysql in my laptop so i received error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb'
```

I don't know how to reset my root password or how to totally reinstall mysql in my laptop.
Some body can help me ??
Sorry about my grammar!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set up your root password during installation, you probably installed it wrongly. You can follow through this quick [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/) to install mysql server on  ubuntu.